# Digital cameras that can take photos directly into a PC

Tags: canon, nikon, software, sony, computer-hardware

I'm looking for a low-cost digital camera that can feed images directly into a PC. By low-cost I mean in the $100-$200 range. This is needed because I'm going to write some software that lets the user interactively tag the image as he clicks it.

As of now, I'm aware of the CHDK (Canon Hack Development Kit) which supports some [500 distinct Canon camera models](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/CHDK), and lets a user take images directly into a PC using the "[PTP extension](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/PTP_Extension)" feature.

> CHDK 1.2 added support for saving images directly over USB, without saving on the SD card.
>
> This is supported for RAW and DNG on all cameras, and for JPEG on some cameras.

Is there any such software or SDK for Sony, Nikon, or any other camera brand that let you takes images straight into a PC? This is also known as "remote capture" in some guides.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need CHDK to accomplish this. I was doing it ten years ago with my little Powershot A520. Including live view and tethered capture using the free Canon CameraWindow software. And it doesn't even support CHDK.

You can find Canon point and shoot cameras pretty cheap used.

Comment: are you certain that the image will only be saved to the PC and not also the memory card. I ask because I do a lot of studio work and I also use the free Canon Software to tether, but the image is always also stored on the Memory card. Can you confirm?

Comment: I recommend that you review the manual for your camera. It explains how to disable saving to the memory card. Same thing if you are going to purchase, the documentation should tell you that.

Comment: Are you saying that if I set my camera to fire without CF then it will automatically save to my Mac? I cannot find any other ref in the manuals of either camera

Comment: The software manual explains it.

Answer (score 1):

Check this? This might help..

http://www.eyefi.com/